# Installing Canopy broke Matplotlib (ImportError: no module named matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, canopy

Ever since I installed [canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/), my [anaconda](http://continuum.io/) version of matplotlib has been broken. I cannot even import it in the command line. I have uninstalled canopy but still have not found success.

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Comment: did it work in canopy?

Comment: don't mix canopy and anaconda, you have mucked up your paths.  Remove both and then re-install.